# Center 3 Uneven Labels - Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, centering

Attached is an image of what I'm trying to center and the attempts I have made using XCode 11.2.1[image]

**How do I center the 3 labels of different sizes (the data for the number will be dynamic also) horizontally in the view?**

Things I have tried to do:

I tried putting a horizontal constraint on the LateBEDView (which contains the 3 labels), but when you view it on the Simulator or Actual Device it puts all the text to the right of the center.  I have tried using spacers (empty views) on both sides but can't figure out what the settings should be? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Put the three labels in a horizontal stack view and then center that stack view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. I'd make this *one* label, which after all is easily centered. Okay, I'll assume you know how to do that.

Then I'd use an attributed string to create the different parts of the string, including the "subscripting". So, first I'd extend the attributed string keys to include the three parts:

```
extension NSAttributedString.Key {
    static let part1 = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: "part1")
    static let part2 = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: "part2")
    static let part3 = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: "part3")
}
```

Then I'd set the label's attributed text:

```
let mas = NSMutableAttributedString()
mas.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Late BED = ", attributes: [
    .font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15),
    .foregroundColor:UIColor.black,
    .part1:"part1"
]))
mas.append(NSAttributedString(string: "20.0", attributes: [
    .font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15),
    .foregroundColor:UIColor.black,
    .part2:"part2"
]))
mas.append(NSAttributedString(string: " Gy(3.0)", attributes: [
    .font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 9),
    .foregroundColor:UIColor.black,
    .baselineOffset:-10,
    .part3:"part3"
]))
self.label.attributedText = mas
```

The result looks like what you've got, and of course you can tweak it as needed:

[image]

Okay, and here's the really clever part. Because I demarcated the three parts of the attributed string, I can find and change the text of any of them, at will. As you say, the data for each number needs to be able to change. That's why you used three labels! But now I'm showing how to do that with *one* label.

For example, let's say I want to change "20.0" to "30.4". That is your second label, and my `.part2`. Here's how you do it:

```
let s = self.label.attributedText
// skip past part 1 and find part 2
var r = NSRange()
let mas = s?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
let _ = mas.attribute(.part2, at: 0, longestEffectiveRange: &r, 
    in: NSRange(location: 0, length: 100))
// find range of part 2
let _ = mas.attribute(.part2, at: r.length, longestEffectiveRange: &r, 
    in: NSRange(location: 0, length: 100))
mas.replaceCharacters(in: r, with: "30.4")
self.label.attributedText = mas
```

Comment: Very nice solution :).  I'll be testing this shortly and give you feedback soon.  I like how it's all one label.